# Python - replace missing dates with sudo date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with missing date values, how should I replace them with `9999-01-01 00:00:00`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('sample-data.xlsx',converters={'sample_date':str})
df['sample_date'] 

output of df['sample_date']:

0    2017-11-08 00:00:00
1    2016-08-03 00:00:00
2    2015-09-29 00:00:00
3    NaT
4    2015-09-29 00:00:00
5    NaT

if df['sample_date'] == "" or df['sample_date'] == None or df['sample_date'] == "NaT" or df['sample_date'] == "NaN":
    df['sample_date'] == "9999-01-01  00:00:00"
```

I am getting error like: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using pandas `fillna()` function to fill the NaT values in your dataframe.

```
df['sample_date'] = df['sample_date'].fillna('9999-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I dont know if this works with `NaT` values, but if my memory serves correct it does.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function.

```
df['sample_date'] =df['sample_date'].fillna("9999-01-01  00:00:00")
```